# Made few changes in stellar core file. Saved it but cannot see the changes in the new transactions i am performing

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk

I have made certain changes in LedgerManagerImpl.cpp file under src-> ledger folder on line approx 68-72

```
  const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_BASE_FEE = 50;
  const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_BASE_RESERVE = 0;
  const uint32_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_MAX_TX_SIZE = 100;
  const int64_t LedgerManager::GENESIS_LEDGER_TOTAL_COINS = 10000000;
```

My aim is to change the base fee to 50, base reserve to 0 and total coins to 10000000.

Although we can change the transaction fees to 1 stroop using 
         var txn = new Stellar.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount, opts={fee:1}) But i want to make changes in the stellar core file.
i want to change the base reserve too. I asked this question to other platform too but didnt get the correct answer.

I simply made the changes to the cpp files but as i have reinstalled the stellar core and tried running my programme but still didnt see any changes.

Any help will really be appreciated.
I have made a private stellar with 2 nodes.

Comment: Values are stored in the ledger, take a look at your latest ledger if they were applied correctly:  https://[yourHorizon]/ledgers/?order=desc&limit=1

Comment: @sui using the above commands giving me the below output
"total_coins": "100000000000.0000000",
        "fee_pool": "0.0000918",
        "base_fee_in_stroops": 1,
        "base_reserve_in_stroops": 1,

It is still not the value which i have set in LedgerManagerImpl.cpp file under src-> ledger folder .
Help me out in unistalling the stellar core.

Comment: From my understanding those constants are start values when initializing a new network. So I guess if you start over with new-db it will probably init the new ledger with those values. Changes can somehow be set with the upgrades command (your question some days ago) but I have not done that before and have absolutely no experience regarding this.

Comment: @sui Thank you so much for the information. Resolved the issue